# Swift: Generate Identifier for Variable

Tags: swift, identifier

I have a large list of NSButtons (80+) that I assign to an array. I've used a numbering scheme to name them and I'd like to generate the identifiers  for them instead of calling them directly by name one at a time.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button120: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button121: NSButton!
var buttons [NSButton]()
```

Currently (in ViewDidLoad()) I'm doing the equivalent of:

```
buttons = [ button120, button121 ]
```

I'd prefer to do something like:

```
for index in 120...121 {
  buttons.append("button\(index)".toIdentifier)
}
```

Can this be done in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an easier solution, view is the parent view of the buttons

```
let buttons = view.subviews.filter { $0 is NSButton}
```

Comment: Yep, thanks. That would work to get all of the buttons in the view (though I'm not sure in what order). Unfortunately that won't solve my problem:  I'm looking for a solution that will let me put groups of buttons in different arrays in a known order (hence the reason I was so careful with the naming of the buttons).

Comment: that's also possible. Assign tags to the buttons in Interface Builder and sort the arrays respectively.

Comment: That's true. I'm already assigning tags according to the naming convention.That would work, though I'd love to know if Swift can allow creation of symbols.

Comment: Modified implementation to use dictionary based on NSButton tag values based on vadian's comments -- thx much for the nudge away from where I was going.